# Evaluate a simple mathematical expression with limited tools, no arrays, and no library functions

Tags: c, getchar

Here's a question from the last year's first "Intro to programming" exam at my uni:

> Using the `getchar()` function read an input sequence consisting of
> numbers, + and - signs. The output should be the result of those
> arithmetical operations.

For example, if the input is `10+13-12+25-5+100`, the output should be `131`.

Now, given that I have a little bit of C experience before attending uni, this problem seems easy to solve using pointers, arrays, etc.

But here's the catch: **on the exam you can only use things that the students were taught so far.** And given that this exam is only like a month after the start of the school year, your options are fairly limited.

You can only use *variables, basic input/output stuff, operators (logical and bitwise), conditional statements and loops, functions*.

That means no: *arrays, strings, pointers, recursion, structures, or basically any other stuff that makes this easy.*

How in the hell do I do this? Today is the second time I've spent 3 hours trying to solve this. I have solved it successfully, but only after "cheating" and using arrays, string functions (`strtol`), and pointers. It's important for me to know how to solve it by the rules, as I'll have similar stuff on the upcoming exam.

Edit: my attempts so far have amounted to using the while loop combined with `getchar()` for input, after which I just get stuck. I don't have the slightest idea of what I should do without using more "tools".

Comment: Hmmm, it will be hard to output the result without arrays nor strings nor recursion. I think it should be possible though.

Comment: It surely is possible. You do not need anything other than a couple of variables for this.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to add what you have tried so far, and why do you think this cannot be done without some of those tools.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I do think it can be done, it's just that it's very hard for me. Like, I hardly even know where to start without a thing like an array.

Comment: Hint: Start by just writing code that will read a single number, character by character, and put its value in an `int`. An operation that will help you here is multiplication by 10.

Comment: Start at the simplest input, what if you are given just a number like "123", how would you consume it?

Comment: Accumulate a number by multiplying by 10 and adding the current digit (less `'0'`). No array is needed. If a non-digit is an operator, remember what you are supposed to do with the next number that you build.

Comment: Then for outputting the result, dividing and modulo with power of 10 (`1, 10, 100, ...`) will be useful to extract each digits.

Comment: Thanks, guys, I get what you are saying. It's obvious when you type it out like that. I'll try to implement the ideas you suggested.

Comment: you should theoretically only need two variables: one to store the result, and one to store the number currently being read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, but it might not be obvious for a beginner. I will not provide a complete program, but rather outline the steps needed to implement this with only a few variables.

First of all, it's important to notice two things:

1. Your input can only contain one of `-`, `+` or any digit (`0123456789`).
2. The `getchar()` function will read one character of input at a time, and will return `EOF` when the end of the input is reached or an error occurs.

Now, onto the solution:

1. Start by reading one character at a time, in a loop. You will only stop if you reach end of input or if an error occurs:

   ```c
   int c;

   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
       // logic here
   }
   ```
2. Start with an accumulator set to `0`, and "add" digits to it every time you encounter a digit.

   ```c
   // outside the loop
   int acc = 0;

   // inside the loop
   if (/* c is a digit */)
           acc = acc * 10 + (c = '0');
   ```

   Hint: that `/* c is a digit */` condition might not be simple, you can put this in the `else` of the check for `-` and `+`.
3. Every time you encounter either `-` or `+`, remember the operation, and each time you encounter an operator, first perform the previous operation and reset the accumulator.

   ```c
   // outside the loop
   int op = 0;
   int result = 0;

   // inside the loop
   if (c == '+' || c == '-') {
       if (op) {
           // there already is a previous operation to complete, do it
           if (op == '+')
               result += acc;
           else
               result -= acc;
       } else {
           // first operation encountered, don't do anything yet
           result = acc;
       }

       acc = 0; // reset
       op = c; // remember the current operation for the future
   }
   ```
4. When you reach the end of the input (i.e. you exit the loop), perform the last operation (same logic inside the `if` from point 3).
5. Output the result:

   You would normally write something like:

   ```c
   printf("%d\n", result);
   ```

   However, if you cannot use string literals (`"%d\n"`) or the `printf()` function, you will have to do so manually using `putchar()`. This is basically the opposite of what we did before to scan numbers into an accumulator.

   1. Print the sign first if needed, and make the value positive:

      ```c
      if (result < 0) {
          putchar('-');
          result = -result;
      }
      ```
   2. Find the maximum power of 10 that is lower than your number:

      ```c
      int div = 1;

      while (result / div / 10)
          div *= 10;
      ```
   3. Use the power to extract and print each digit by division and modulo by 10:

      ```c
      while (div) {
          putchar('0' + ((result / div) % 10));
          div /= 10;
      }
      ```

      Note: the `'0' +` at the beginning is used to convert digits (from 0 to 10) to the relative ASCII character.
   4. End with a newline:

      ```c
      putchar('\n');
      ```

Comment: `"%d\n"` is a string. Strings are forbidden here.

Comment: @MikeCAT ah... string literals too... ok that's annoying, I'll update.

Comment: @MikeCAT I somewhat doubt that the format string counts. Yes, you can write your own printf for integers, but that seems... pointless. But the OP must decide that.

Answer (score 3):

When writing a parser, I typically find myself that I "buffer" the next operation that "will be done". When the input changes state - you are reading digits, but then you read an operation - then you execute the "buffered" action and buffer the next operation that will be done in the future.

Example:

```
10+13-12
^^        - we read 10
  ^       - result=10  - we buffer that we *will* have to do + in the future
   ^^     - reading 13
     ^    - och we stopped reading numbers!
            we execute _buffered_ operation `+` , so we do result += 13
            and buffer `-` to be done in the future
      ^^  - we read 12
        ^ - och, EOF! we execute buffered operation `-` , so we do result -= 12
          - etc.
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int result = 0; // represents current result
    int temp = 0; // the temporary number that we read into
    int op = 0; // represents the _next_ operation that _will_ be done
    while (1) {
        int c = getchar();
        switch (c) {
        // we read an operation, so we should calculate _the previous_ operation
        // or this is end of our string
        case '+': case '-': case EOF:
            if (op == 0) {
                // we have nothing so far, so start with first number
                result = temp;
            } else if (op == '+') {
                result += temp;
            } else if (op == '-') { 
                result -= temp;
            }
            // the next operation we will do in future is stored in op
            op = c;
            // current number starts from 0
            temp = 0;
            break;
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            // read a digit - increment temporary number
            temp *= 10;
            temp += c - '0';
            break;
        }
        // we quit here, the result for last operation is calculated above
        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
   
    // As I see it was mentioned that "%d\n" is a string,
    // here's the simplest algorithm for printing digits in a number.
    // Extract one digit from the greatest position and continue up
    // to the last digit in a number.

    // Take negative numbers and throw them out the window.
    if (result < 0) {
         putchar('-');
         result = -result;
    }
    // Our program currently supports printing numbers up to 10000.
    int divisor = 10000;
    // 000100 should print as 100 - we need to remember we printed non-zero
    int was_not_zero = 0;
    while (divisor != 0) {
        // extract one digit at position from divisor
        int digit = result / divisor % 10;
        // if the digit is not zero, or
        // we already printed anything
        if (digit != 0 || was_not_zero) {
            // print the digit
            putchar(digit + '0');
            was_not_zero = 1;
        }
        // the next digit will be to the right
        divisor /= 10;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void operate(int * sum, int * n, char todo) {
    if (todo == 1)        *sum += *n;
    else if (todo == -1)  *sum -= *n;
    printf("%s %d\n", todo == 1 ? "ADD :" : "SUB :", *n); 
    *n = 0; 
}

int main()
{
    char * problem = "10+13-12+25-5+100";
    int len = strlen(problem);
    int i=0;
    char c;
    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    char todo = 1;
    while(i < len)
    {
        c = problem[i++];
        if (c < 48 || c >= 58) 
        {
            // Adds or subtracts previous and prepare next
            operate(&sum, &n, todo);
            if (c == '+') todo = 1; 
            else if  (c == '-') todo = -1; 
        } 
        else
        {
            // Collects an integer
            if (n) n *= 10;
            n += c - 48;
        } 
    }
    operate(&sum, &n, todo); // Last pass

    printf("SUM => %d\n", sum); // => 131
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void do_operation(char next_operation, int * result, int * number){
    if (next_operation == '+'){
        *result += *number;
        *number = 0;
    } else if (next_operation == '-'){
        *result -= *number;
        *number = 0;
    } else {
        printf("Unknown operation error.");   
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char c;
    int number = 0;
    int result = 0;
    char next_operation = '+';

    do {
        c = getchar();
        if( c >= '0' && c <= '9' ){
            number = number * 10 + c - 48;
        } else if (c == '+'){
            do_operation(next_operation, &result, &number);
            next_operation = '+';
        } else if (c == '-'){
            do_operation(next_operation, &result, &number);
            next_operation = '-';
        } else {
            do_operation(next_operation, &result, &number);
        }
    } while (c != '\n');

    printf("%d", result);
}
```